# How do I use external web camera though USB OTG on Huawei Honor 6?

Tags: usb, kernel, usb-on-the-go, webcam, huawei-honor-6

Built-in kernel does not come with USB Video support and when using sideloaded `uvcvideo.ko` the camera works very bad (image is distorted, the device often crash). I can barely get even single 160x120 frames.

FFmpeg says `[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa57320] The v4l2 frame is 32712 bytes, but 38400 bytes are expected` (the bigger frame size, the sooner).

dmesg says something like `[ 1610.497185] [7168.0, ffmpeg] cma: dma_alloc_from_contiguous(cma e44c14c0, count 10, align 4)`.

I tried various `quirks` parameters for the `uvcvideo.ko` module, but nothing helps.

How do I make use of external USB camera on my device? Are there any patches/hackes available?

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to your question ? I'm facing the same one.

Comment: Other camera works better (i.e only in 320x240 mode with device slowing down and sometimes rebooting, but DashCam nonetheless showing the picture). Maybe that's because of it can stream less than 15 FPS...

Comment: Which "the same one" question do you face? "How to connect USB camera to Android"? or "How to fix USB OTG mode to make v4l2 work reliably on Huawei Honor 6"?

Comment: Workaround: use some single board computer (like [C.H.I.P](https://getchip.com/)) that will capture from camera and re-stream on Wi-Fi for MXPlayer to consume (with the approriate delay). Not tested, I can try it...